# Can't configure the test network settings

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template, substrate-node, zombienet

I am trying to Configure the test network settings. I am following this [tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/test/simulate-parachains/).

This is my `config.toml` file

```
[relaychain]

default_command = "./binaries/polkadot/polkadot"
default_args = ["-lparachain=debug"]

chain = "rococo-local"

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "alice"

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "bob"

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "charlie"

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "dave"

[[parachains]]
id = 1000
cumulus_based = true

[parachains.collator]
name = "parachain-A-1000-collator01"
command = "./binaries/parachain-template/parachain-template-node"

[[parachains]]
id = 1001
cumulus_based = true

[parachains.collator]
name = "parachain-B-1001-collator01"
command = "./binaries/parachain-template/parachain-template-node"
```

When I start test network using `./zombienet-macos spawn config.toml -p native` command, network is started but I get this warning,

```
(node:28868) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `zombienet-macos --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:50697/metrics

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:50705/metrics

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:50701/metrics

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:50709/metrics
```

Why I am getting this warning? How to fix this or should I ignore?

and after some time it terminate automatically with this error,

```
Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:52347/metrics

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:52343/metrics

     Error:  
         Timeout(300), "getting desired metric value 1 within 300 secs".


     Error:  
         Timeout(300), "getting desired metric value 1 within 300 secs".


     Error:  
         Timeout(300), "getting desired metric value 1 within 300 secs".


     Error:  
         Timeout(300), "getting desired metric value 1 within 300 secs".

Error:       Error: At least one of the nodes fails to start

undefined
┌────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Node'              │ /var/folders/q3/d699hkpx49xfy236ph7sltr40000gn/T/zombie-d3059dd228663607be58ce72a2009ae4_-34898-V… │
│ s logs:            │                                                                                                    │
│ m                  │                                                                                                    │
└────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:52335/metrics

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:52339/metrics

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:52347/metrics

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:52343/metrics
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

Comment: Hi, can you check if you are running the latest version of zombienet (v1.3.63)

Comment: ./zombienet-macos version
`1.3.30`. Do i need to update @pepoviola?

Comment: Yes, please. You need to update to the latest version `v1.3.63` and should works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @pepoviola now my latest version is `v1.3.63` and now I am getting warning error.

Comment: Looks like one of the nodes didn't start as expected, can you check the logs of the collators ?

Comment: @pepoviola where can I find logs of the collators?

Comment: @pepoviola [pic-1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-o-cH1gt9oIGHTsoLTq5RrjySv9m-xPr/view?usp=drive_link) and [pic-2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qnasTuTInjYT1pbwdj1MQMJUgPYgIwlb/view?usp=drive_link) do you means this logs?

Comment: Make sure that your parachain is on similar release as your polkadot binary (not sure whether this is a must but it helped me once).

Comment: @Ganesh11, no. I mean the logs in this directory `/var/folders/q3/d699hkpx49xfy236ph7sltr40000gn/T/zombie-d3059dd228663607be58ce72a2009ae4_-34898-V...` (the full path is elided), and then you will se the logs for the nodes (in the form of <node_name>.log). In general this kind of errors can happen if the node crash or if the node doesn't expose prometheus metrics.

Comment: @pepoviola [pic-3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TQ1DjCFbph_tIZ2Jhzoc5kiyC3NtuFlZ/view?usp=drive_link) this is the logs of the collators. I haven't found any error message here.

Comment: @Ganesh11, that looks ok. Are the rest of the nodes (alice, bob, etc) also ok? I will trying to reproduce the same steps from the tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: @pepoviola there is error in `alice.log` `Error: 
   0: [91mWorker binaries could not be found, make sure polkadot was built/installed correctly. Searched given workers path (None), polkadot binary path ("/Users/ganesholi/binaries/polkadot"), and lib path (/usr/lib/polkadot), workers names: None[0m`. may be this is issue

Comment: @Ganesh11, yes. That the issue. Did you compile `polkadot` from master? can you try compile the last release `v1.0.0`?

Comment: yes I compile from master

Comment: Since https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/7337, polkadot will have two other  binaries (workers) that you need to compile. Can you please compile from tag `v1.0.0` and will works as expected.

Comment: @pepoviola now it works fine, can you suggest some more resources so that I can learn more.

Comment: Please provide the answer @Ganesh11

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas I switch to `release-v1.0.0` branch, recompile and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to `release-v1.0.0` branch and recompile. This is due to the fact that on master, since [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/7337), polkadot has two other binaries (workers) that you need to compile.